# How to select nodes for Enzyme testing when class names are not static?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I would like to test the following component using Enzyme:

```
export class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, numOrders } = this.props;

        return (
            <header>
                <div className={classes.numOrders}>
                    {numOrders}
                </div>
                ...
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

What's the best way to select the `div` that's showing the number of orders. Note that the class name is dynamically generated (using JSS), so it's not a good choice. Is there any other reasonable way/best practice for doing this? (I don't want to add CSS #id's on these nodes.)

Comment: In this case it seems you could just use the `classes` prop to pass a class name when you mount the component in your test, and then `find` that class name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What I like to do here is use `data` attributes for testing and then use attribute selector in Enzyme.

It would look something like this:

```
export class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { classes, numOrders } = this.props;

        return (
            <header>
                <div className={classes.numOrders} data-testid="SomeName">
                    {numOrders}
                </div>
                ...
            </header>
        );
    }
}
```

And the selector in Enzyme would be like:

```
wrapper.find('[data-testid="SomeName"]');
```

more info: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html

Comment: I ended up using the same. Enzyme does not seem to support full css selectors, like when there is multiple class names and selection one in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a piece of code to help that, you can find the whole description on my [pull request](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/1987) (it was merged already), to select this div, now you can use .hasClass() with a regex expression, for example, if you are using material-ui, in dev environment the classes follow the same pattern, so you are able to select this way:

```
expect(hasClassName(node, /(MyComponent)-(hide)-(\d+)/)).to.equal(true)
```